# Wikijs Graphql: How to create multiple users at a time?

Tags: graphql, wiki.js

I am trying to create multiple users at a time from a CSV file. Right now I am only able to create one user at a time using the following mutation:

```
mutation {
  users {
    create (
       email: ""
       name: ""
       passwordRaw:: ""
       providerKey: ""
       groups: [1]
       mustChangePassword: true
       sendWelcomeEmail: false
    ) {
       responseResult {
              succeeded
              slug
              message
       }
        user {
              id
        }
       }
      }
     }
```

This is working fine for creating a single user. I want to make it easy for me to create multiple users at a time.

Answer (score 1):

In GraphQL, you can create queries with numerous user mutations, allowing for efficient user data management through operations like creation, updates, and deletions in a single request. This approach streamlines data processes and improves application performance.

The syntax for Wiki.Js user create mutation would be:

```
mutation {
    users {
    u1: create(
        email:"userA@local.corp"
        name:"User 1"
        passwordRaw:"ChangeMe@123"
            providerKey:"local"
        groups: [1]
        mustChangePassword: true
        sendWelcomeEmail: false
    ){ responseResult {succeeded,message}  }
    
    u2: create(
        email:"userB@local.corp"
        name:"User 2"
        passwordRaw:"ChangeMe@123"
            providerKey:"local"
        groups: [1]
        mustChangePassword: true
        sendWelcomeEmail: false
    ){ responseResult {succeeded,message} }
    
    NewUser3: create(
        email:"user3@local.corp"
        name:"User 2"
        passwordRaw:"ChangeMe@123"
            providerKey:"local"
        groups: [1]
        mustChangePassword: true
        sendWelcomeEmail: false
    ){ responseResult {succeeded,message} }
    
  }
}
```